# How to Initialize an array for a struct with not default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I want to initialize an array of struct type. Currently i am doing this

```
struct Gene 
{
    int **boxes;
    int fitness;

    Gene()
    {
        boxes = new int*[get_the_number]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < get_the_number; ++i) {
            boxes[i] = new int[get_the_number];
        }
    }
};
```

and I am initializing like this

```
Gene * P = new Gene [t];
```

It is working fine and i can do my work. It calls the default constructor which i have written itself and work is done. But now, i want to pass a parameter into the default constructor. I changed my constructor to this.

```
Gene(int n)
```

But I don't know how to initialize it, i did this

```
Gene * P= new Gene (2) [t];
```

But it gives me error that "No suitable conversion from Gene* to Gene exists". I know that I can write the setter function and do what I want to do there or instead of making an array of Gene type I can make an array of Gene* and at each index I can initialize `new Gene(2)`. But I  don't want to do because I don't need to pass a variable. I just wanted to know that can't I call my constructor which takes a parameter.

Can't I do something like `Gene * P= new Gene(2)[t];`?

I mean the compiler is calling that constructor which doesn't take a parameter. Can't it call this constructor instead of that?
Thank you,

*p.s.:* I know its a beginners question but I am back to C++ after a long time so I don't quiet remember things.

Comment: learn to use std::vector instead.

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible with pure pointers, but that kind of stuff is generally done only when you _implement_ `std::vector`-like class.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would second the suggestion to use `std::vector` instead of calling `new[]` and `delete[]` yourself.  You will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Second, I can think of a way to do what I think you want.  I can't imagine what kind of syntax you would expect if each object were to be created with different parameters (similar to Lisp's `map`), so I'm going to assume that you want each object to be created with the same parameters, or with easily computed parameters.

#### `std::vector` with all identical objects:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Gene> P(size, Gene(2));
```

#### `std::vector` with similar but not identical objects:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int foo = 0;
std::vector<Gene> P;
// you can omit the next line; back_inserter will make sure the vector grows appropriately
P.reserve(size); 
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(P), size, [&foo](){ Gene(++foo); });
```

You can get a lot fancier in the lambda that creates a `Gene` object, or you could use a normal function instead of a lambda.

#### new[] with identical objects:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

Gene* P = new Gene[size];
std::fill_n(P, size, Gene(2));
```

#### new[] with similar objects:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int foo = 0;
Gene* P = new Gene[size];
std::generate_n(P, size, [&foo]() { Gene(++foo); });
```

Both cases with `new[]` create default objects that are immediately overwritten with `fill_n` or `generate_n` (on a decent implementation, the `vector` approach should not have this problem).  That's probably nothing to worry about, but I feel an obligation to mention it.  The bigger problem is that writing exception safe code with plain `new[]` and `delete[]` is nearly impossible.  Writing exception safe code with `vector` is far easier.

And, yes, I would recommend the same kind of changes to `Gene` for the same reason (as of now, `Gene` simply isn't exception safe; which is bad given that `new[]` reports failure by throwing an exception):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Gene {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> boxes;
    int fitness;
    static const size_t DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_BOXES = 20;

    Gene() : boxes(DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_BOXES), fitness(0)
    {
        std::for_each(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(),
                      [](std::vector<int>& b) { b.resize(DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_BOXES); });
    }

    Gene(size_t N) : boxes(N), fitness(0)
    {
        std::for_each(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(),
                      [N](std::vector<int>& b) { b.resize(N); });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way to do this, `new[]` only allows default or no initialization.
You could have a `for` and initialize each of them (which sounds to me like the easiest solution), but there are also more complicated ways to create the in memory objects as (`void*`) and use `reinterpret_cast` to cast them to `Gene*` but in the end you'll still need to call the c-tors for each of the created instance of the classes

Comment: I would clarify that it's actually `new[]` that only allows for default initialization - there's nothing wrong with `ptr = new SomeClass(that, takes, many, arguments, in, the, constructor);` for a single object... It's the array case that has the restriction, because there's no convenient way to specify different sets of constructor arguments for each element in the array...

Comment: Yeah twalberg you are right, its only with the array

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is likely not what you want. Do you have good reason to really use all of those pointers? There is a reason `std::vector` was invented and best practices (as this seems to be a beginner question, this seems relevant) demand you to start using some C++ goodness instead of those pesky C pointers.

With `std::vector`, you can specify the default element you want your vector with:

```
Gene gene(<some gene constructor call here>);
```

The following [vector constructor call](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructs a vector of genes with 17 identical copies of `gene`

```
std::vector<Gene> gene_pool(17, gene);
```

*p.s.:* If you even know the size of the vector/array/list/container at compile time as others are suggesting, have a look at [`std::array`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 2):

If you like to avoid new/delete in your code:

```
#include <vector>

class Gene
{
    public:
    std::size_t extent;
    std::vector<int> boxes;

    Gene(int n) : extent(n), boxes(n*n, int(0)) {}
    int operator () (unsigned row, unsigned col) {
        return boxes[row * extent + col];
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::size_t t = 42;
    std::vector<Gene> P(t, Gene(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Each Gene has it's own boxes (initialized with zero) after construction.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, don't use new unless you really don't know the size of the array until runtime.

If you use a static array, you can use the array's initialization list:

```
Gene array[x] = {Gene()};
```

Alternatively, you can use memcpy:

```
Gene default;
for (int i=0; i < size; i++} 
{
   memcpy (&(array[i]), &default, sizeof(Gene));
}
```

The third option is to use a vector

```
std::vector<Gene> array(size, Gene());
```

Comment: `memcpy` is not an appropriate suggestion for C++.

Comment: It's not appropriate for people who don't know how to use it.

Comment: It's not appropriate, period. `std::move` or `operator =()` would be more appropriate

Comment: @user2036161 OP most certainly doesn't know how to use `memcpy` in C++; if you suggest using it, you should explain when it's safe to (e.g. if the type in question is a POD, which it isn't).

Comment: std::move was added with C++11, what if your project is not using C++11? Assignment is fine, I grant you that, but there is nothing wrong with memcpy.

Comment: It would be arbitrary to assume the OP cannot use the current C++ standard. And in C++03, you'd still want to use `std::copy` or `operator =()`. The only reason to use `memcpy` in C++ is when you want to copy some odd-sized slice of memory blob, not ever for copying whole objects.

Comment: Some projects and companies do refuse to use C++11; until recently, Google was one such company ( http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#C++11 ).  However, it's worth mentioning that C++11 is now three years old and there have been free implementations available for most of that time.  I think it's generally reasonable to assume that a questioner can use C++11 unless they say otherwise.